# How to create a function that graphs objects in haskell in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, codeworld

How to Format
► put returns between paragraphs

► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end

► *italic* or **bold**

► indent code by 4 spaces

Answer (score 2):

```
graphicToPic (s c p) = ...
```

This is nonsense.  You should use the constructor to destruct the value:

```
graphicToPic (Graphic s c p) = ...
```